# parinfer-rust-mode doesn't get enabled automatically with clojure-mode via hook

Tags: hooks, minor-mode, clojure

The problem: upon opening a `.clj` file, the `clojure-mode` correctly starts. However, `parinfer-rust-mode` doesn't, despite being added to a `clojure-mode-hook`.

The setup (everything related to clojure from my config):

```lisp
;; clojure
(use-package clojure-mode
  :init
  (setq clojure-indent-style 'align-arguments)
  (setq clojure-align-forms-automatically t))

;; extra highlight
(use-package clojure-mode-extra-font-locking)

;; cider
(use-package cider)

;; parinfer disables https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElectricPair mode. Look into re-enabling it for other languages I work in
(use-package parinfer-rust-mode
  :hook clojure-mode
  :init
  (setq parinfer-rust-auto-download t))
```

`C-h v clojure-mode-hook`:

```
clojure-mode-hook is a variable defined in ‘clojure-mode.el’.

Its value is shown below.

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Hook run after entering Clojure mode.
No problems result if this variable is not bound.
‘add-hook’ automatically binds it.  (This is true for all hook variables.)

Value:
(parinfer-rust-mode #f(compiled-function
                       ()
                       #<bytecode -0x1e6605021ebab616>)
                    (closure
                     (t)
                     nil
                     (set
                      (make-local-variable 'sesman-system)
                      'CIDER))
                    clojure--check-wrong-major-mode)
```

If I manually eval `(parinfer-rust-mode)`, mode gets enabled without any warnings or such.

I also tried to remove `:hook` from `use-package` and add it manually like so -

```
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook #'parinfer-rust-mode)
```

but it doesn't change anything, `parinfer-rust-mode` still doesn't start automatically.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out everything was working fine, except the files that I thought would be opened would not be opened really, and instead get loaded from some form of cache or something, apparently with already defined enabled modes. I'm not well-versed in emacs so can't pin-point it, but I know `find-alternate-file` (`C-x C-v`) on a Clojure buffer would re-run all the modes, all the hooks and everything would work out well.